# How to read the temperature from a MLX90393 using python?

Tags: python, i2c, spi

Besides the magnetic field, I would like to read also the temperature from a [MLX90393 (please find the datasheet here)](https://media.melexis.com/-/media/files/documents/datasheets/mlx90393-datasheet-melexis.pdf)
This code example that uses the [smbus library](http://www.pibits.net/code/raspberry-pi-and-mlx90393-magnetic-field-sensor-example.php) (careful: python2.x) works well.

However, I can now manage to also read the temperature. I came this far:
On p20 the command list says that I need to write 0100zyxt = 01001111 (hex: 4F, so bus.write_byte(0x0C, 0x3E) -> bus.write_byte(0x0C, 0x3F) ) and I also need to read the temp as follows:

```
data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(mlx90393_address, 0x4F, 9)
# Convert the data
temp= data[1] * 256 + data[2]
if temp > 32767 :
    temp -= 65536
print(temp) 
xMag = data[3] * 256 + data[4]
if xMag > 32767 :
    xMag -= 65536
print(xMag)
yMag = data[5] * 256 + data[6]
if yMag > 32767 :
    yMag -= 65536
print(yMag)
zMag = data[7] * 256 + data[8]
if zMag > 32767 :
    zMag -= 65536
print(zMag)
```

The sensor data that I receive is fine but I need to convert the temperature reading now to the real value. Around 22°C it reads -19000 for

```
temp= data[1] * 256 + data[2]
```

Comment: The temperature reading isn't in degrees; according to the datasheet, there is a scaling factor of 45.2, with an offset of 46244 at 25 degrees.  So `(temp - 46244) / 45.2 + 25` (and get rid of the `-= 65536` part, the raw reading is unsigned).

Comment: @jasonharper thanks. that's the correct answer!